# PuTTY very slow to launch (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, putty

I just set up a new computer at work, and I noticed PuTTY is very slow to open (it takes over 5 seconds, usually even around 9-10s). plink.exe suffers from the same issue, although it's not as slow (takes about 1 second).

If I fire up an old version (for instance 0.63, as I had a backup of it handy), it opens instantly (plink.exe) or almost instantly (putty.exe), like it used to.

Is it normal behavior that the new putty is so slow to start up? Is there some kind of configuration that could make it load as fast as it used to?

I'm using Windows 10 x64, and I tried both PuTTY 32 and 64 bits.

Comment: I am experiencing same issue with putty 0.70 on Windows 7. Takes lot of time to start up. Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using PuTTY 0.70 too

Comment: One thing you could do that _may_ help you find the answer is to install something like Wireshark and find out if the new version of Putty is trying to access a network resource that the old version didn't.

Comment: Actually, eventually the problem was "solved" by getting the putty provided in the zip distribution instead of directly downloading putty.exe standalone. I suspect the file being tagged as downloaded from the Internet might be the cause of my trouble, although at no point I got any alert about it. Weird :s

Answer (score 1):

I have PuTTY 0.71 64-bit on Windows 10. PuTTY was taking long to load when I used Windows search bar and clicked on the PuTTY app. I went into C:\Program Files\PuTTY and created a desktop shortcut for putty.exe (right click on putty.exe -> Send to -> Desktop (create shortcut)). After that, it loads quickly now.

Comment: So strange but worked for me!!! Thanks man